# simplify number validation in if statement JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am validating my time in this way

```
if (
  timeInMins != 0 &&
  timeInMins != "0" &&
  timeInMins != undefined &&
  timeInMins != "undefined" &&
  timeInMins != null &&
  timeInMins != "" &&
  !isNaN(timeInMins)
) {
  timeInMinsCumulative += parseFloat(timeInMins);
}
```

Is there any way to make this ugly if-check to sophisticated code?

Comment: `!= 0` and `!= "0"` are the same in JS, this way you only compare its value, if you want to compare a variable's type, use `!==` or `===`. And to better answer your question, I recommend you to check truthy and falsy values in JS, it could help

Comment: typeof `timeInMins == 'number'` ... will return true only if `timeInMins` it's of type number ... and it will be like that only if containing a valid number. Any other check will be pointless and redundant. `isNaN` returns false also with boolean values

Comment: You can use if(timeInMins   *1  > 0)

Comment: Seems you don't even need that if condition: `timeInMinsCumulative += +timeInMins || 0;`

Answer (score 0):

This uses the coercion behavior of JavaScript and the logical AND operator to simplify your code. The following is very nearly equivalent to your code, but it will also guard against the arguments `false` and `0n`.

```js
if (timeInMins &&
    timeInMins !== '0' &&
    timeInMins !== 'undefined') {
  // whatever          
}
```

Questions for you: do you really expect to ever get the string `'undefined'` passed to you? Why do you want to guard against `'0'` being sent to `parseFloat`? Are you sure `parseInt` is not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

There are 6 falsy values in javascript: `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`, `0`, `""` (empty string), and `false` of course.

So, you can just write

```
if (timeInMins && timeInMin !== '0') {
          timeInMinsCumulative += parseFloat(timeInMins);
}
```

Comment: And BigInt's zero: `0n`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to check if `timeInMins` is precise `Number` type or not.

```js
function isValidNumber(num) {
  return typeof num === "number" && !isNaN(num);
}

console.log(isValidNumber(""));
console.log(isValidNumber(undefined));
console.log(isValidNumber(NaN));
console.log(isValidNumber("undefined"));
console.log(isValidNumber(true));
console.log(isValidNumber(false));
console.log(isValidNumber(0));
console.log(isValidNumber("0"));
console.log(isValidNumber(1.234));
```